# Summon/data merge villager with Explorer Map trade

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

As the title states, I would like to add an explorer map to a summon villager command but nothing seems to be working. More specifically, I would like to append that trade to an existing villager. Is that possible? I cannot seem to find anything.

To clarify, I am looking for the nbt structure to add an explorer map trade to a villager.